# CUG login not working on publish servers after restart

Tags: aem

After restarting our AEM 6.1 (no SP) publish servers, the login for CUG protected sites is no longer working. CUGSupportImpl is marked "enabled" instead of "active". Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug with AEM. If you have a CUG-definition that's empty (CUG enabled, but no group selected) the CUGSupport component will deactivate itself on startup. 
The weird thing is that it is working fine UNTIL you restart your publish instance because there is a sanity check that is only executed on startup.

AFAIK adobe provided a hotfix for this issue for both AEM 6.0 and 6.1.

As a workaround you might deactivate the CUG or add a dummy group/user then activate the page to update the settings on publish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you give me the number of the hotfix package?

Comment: I just checked, both hotfixes were private hotfixes for the project I worked with at that time. So you need to talk to Adobe or check if the problem is solved with SP1